# How to set the value of a boost::optional member variable in a setter method?

Tags: c++, boost

I can't publish my exact code, but I have a class `Mike` where I want it to contain a member variable of a custom object type `Bob`. `Bob` may not be set on construction of `Mike`, but I want it to be set later when a setter method is called. I'm trying to use a `boost::optional<Bob>` for this, in the following manner:

```
class Mike
{
  public:
    void setBob(const Bob& bob)
    {
      m_bob = bob;
    }
    boost::optional<Bob> getBob() const
    {
      return m_bob;
    }
  private:
    boost::optional<Bob> m_bob;
}
```

This is giving the error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘Bob& Bob::operator=(const Bob&)’
     void assign_value ( argument_type val, is_not_reference_tag ) { get_impl() = val; }
```

I've also tried replacing the line

```
m_bob = bob;
```

with

```
m_bob = boost::optional<Bob>(bob);
```

but this results in an almost identical error.

The `Bob` class looks like this:

```
class Bob
{
  public:
    Bob(const double value) : m_value(value)
    {
    }
  private:
    const double m_value;
};
```

Any idea what the correct way to do this is?

Comment: `Bob` seems to be non-assignable and non-copyable. If that's the case, you can't assign it to a data member, irrespective of whether you use `std::optional` around it or not.

Comment: Nothing to do with this code, everything to do with he semantics of `Bob`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is `Bob`? Do you get the same error with a `optional<int>` ? Do you get the same error with a non-optional `Bob` ?

Comment: With a non-optional `Bob` I get an error due to the face `Bob` has no default constructor. `Bob` has to take several arguments into its constructor, and therefore having an empty `Bob` member variable is not possible when constructing a `Mike`. Could this be what is causing this problem as well?

Comment: it could be. Please show a mcve then we can know for sure

Comment: replacing `Bob` with `int` doesn't produce the error, so it seems it probably is a problem with `Bob`. Not sure exactly how I can show an example of `Bob`, as it's commercial code, which is extremely annoying.

Comment: you dont have to show your exact code. You have to show an example that reproduces the problem. Write a `struct Bob {};` that mimics the real Bob

Comment: Maybe read again: [mcve] ;)

Comment: I mean the problem and solution is clear: Your bob has no `Bob& Bob::operator=(const Bob&)` and you need to supply one. But it is rather pointless to write this as answer....

Comment: I've given an example of a `Bob` that will produce a similar error. Removing the `const` from the `m_value` member variable in `Bob` solves the error, but doesn't solve the problem as I want it to be `const`.

Comment: `m_bob = bob` --> `m_bob.emplace(bob)` ?

Comment: After some reading round the subject, and chatting to some more experienced C++ developers, I've decided that the best solution is to not have a const member variable. They seem to be more trouble that they're worth in many instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default assignment operator of `Bob` is deleted as it is not possible to update the value of `m_value` due to it being `const`.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Make `m_value` non `const`. It is unusual to have a `const` member in a class (though perfectly valid). It would be more usual to use `const Bob` which would then make the member `const` too.
2. Assign the new value to the optional using `emplace`, this destroys the old value and creates a new value instead of assigning to the old value if it exists. Depending on the exact nature of `Bob` this might be slightly more expensive?

   ```
   void setBob(const Bob& bob)
   {
      m_bob.emplace(bob);
   }
   ```

Comment: I've decided to go with option 1, as having a const member variable could cause similar problems further down the line in my software. The value `m_value` shouldn't be changed, but keeping it const seems to not be worth the trouble for my use case.